# Issue when login using identity user I get deadlock on PasswordSignInAsync?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I work on blazor server web app with .net core 7 . I face issue deadlock when login with user identity

```
 var asignin = signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userDto.UserName, "Coding@1234?", false, false).Result;
```

and Task Status always WaitForActivation on debugging

PasswordSignInAsync is function on identity user to check valid user name and password to login success.

but when debug it stuck and hang

my code as below:

```
    [Inject]
    public UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    public RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    public SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager { get; set; }
    public  string checkIdentity()
        {
            string Msg = null;
            UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
            userDto.UserName = UserName;
            userDto.Password = Password;
            var user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(userDto.UserName).Result;
            if (user != null)
            {
                var passwordCheck = userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, "Coding@1234?").Result;
                if (passwordCheck)
                {
                    var asignin = signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userDto.UserName, "Coding@1234?", false, false).Result;
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    Msg = "User Not Have Identity";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Msg = "User Not Have Identity";
            }
            return Msg;
        }
```

How to solve this issue?

**updated answer**

when call function I get error as below:

```
string checkidentity = checkIdentity()
```

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>' to 'string'

**updated answer**

when test it and break point on line `PasswordSignInAsync` then add watch I get issues on debug

```
signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userDto.UserName, "Coding@1234?", false, false)   The function evaluation requires all threads to run.    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult>
```

so how to solve it .

**updated answer**

Issue still exist

what I do as following:

1. open visual studio options -debugging-remove check mark from  enable property evaluation and other.
2. close visual studio and then open it again
3. build full project then run
4. it give me same issue evaluation function require all thread to run

evaluation function need all threads to run

[image]

**updated answer :**

as image you tell me i click on button and I get below:

```
Id = 225, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

**Updated answer**

when debug this line signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync by f10 it go and

not back
so what I do to solve issue and are this issue will display when

publish app or this is only on compile time only

Comment: so how to call it because when call it string checkidentity = checkIdentity(); it give me error error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>' to 'string'

Comment: can you check updated answer

Comment: i appreciate your support but still yet not solve issue

Comment: i updated my answer i do exactly as you post but issue still exist

Comment: i updated answer please check it

Comment: you should pass that line code and see the result press F10

Comment: i post this question because when i debug signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync it take too much time so what i do to prevent take too much time on that line also it hange and not come back after debug this line

Comment: so what this issue and are that also will done when publish application on run time

Comment: check last updated answer

Comment: you should check the asignin variable for the result

Comment: and you should use logging in your system when exception happen in runtime

Comment: but this issue not have any solution or any work around or alternative solution

Comment: I think you forgot to make method Async : Error cs4032

Comment: example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4032

Comment: i already put async and nothing changed so how to solve issue

Comment: so are there are any solution for solve issue

Comment: Have you tried change `var user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(userDto.UserName).Result;` to `var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userDto.UserName);`?

Comment: yes exactly yes and give me same issue

Answer (score 0):

This methods are Async but you are using them in sync way with `.Result()`

Use them in right way

```
public async Task<string> checkIdentity()
{
        string Msg = null;
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        userDto.UserName = UserName;
        userDto.Password = Password;
        var user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(userDto.UserName).Result;
        if (user != null)
        {
            var passwordCheck = await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, "Coding@1234?");
            if (passwordCheck)
            {
                var asignin = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userDto.UserName, "Coding@1234?", false, false);
                
            }
            else
            {
                Msg = "User Not Have Identity";
           
            }


        }
        else
        {
            Msg = "User Not Have Identity";

        }
        return Msg;
}
```

First Edit :

The method that you write below code in it should be async too

```
string checkidentity = await checkIdentity();
```

Second Edit:

Thats beacause of visual studio debugger
[Check This link for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/eliofek/why-do-we-get-the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to-run)

Third Edit :

Click on that icon it will show the result
[image: Result]